# How to write entry_points argument for multiple Click CLI functions?

Tags: python, command-line-interface, setuptools, python-click

I'm trying to configure setuptools and Click module for multiple functions.

Click documentation instructs in [Nesting Commands](http://click.pocoo.org/5/quickstart/#nesting-commands) section to use `click.group()`.

How do you write the entry_points for multiple CLick CLI functions?

I was toying with they syntax, and I managed to get something working but I can't recreate it. I was something like this,

```
entry_points='''
    [console_scripts]
    somefunc=yourscript:somefunc
    morefunc=yourscript:morefunc
'''
```

Following the sample given below, I converted the syntax to a dictionary:

```
entry_points= {'console_scripts': 
        ['somefunc = yourscript:somefunc',
        'morefunc = yourscript:morefunc'
    ]},
```

After I reinstalled, calling the script raised this error:

```
(clickenv) > somefunc          
Traceback (most recent call last):
[...]
    raise TypeError('Attempted to convert a callback into a '
TypeError: Attempted to convert a callback into a command twice.
```

---

The way I made this work the first time, was I installed the script, and then gradually changed the code through the various examples. At one point, just as described in the docs, I called the script with `$ yourscript somefunc`. However, when I recreated the pattern in my project I got that error.

Here I've uninstalled and reinstalled (even though its advertised as unnecessary, `pip install -e .`) and removed the second entrypoint. Here's my testing example. The function `morefunc` requires a .txt input file.

```
# yourscript.py
import click

@click.command()
@click.group()
def cli():
    pass

@cli.command()
def somefunc():
    click.echo('Hello World!')

@cli.command()
@click.argument('input', type=click.File('rb'))
@click.option('--saveas', default='HelloWorld.txt', type=click.File('wb'))
def morefunc(input, saveas):
    while True:
        chunk = input.read(1024)
        if not chunk:
            break
        saveas.write(chunk)

# setup.py
from setuptools import setup
setup(
    name='ClickCLITest',
    version='0.1',
    py_modules=['yourscript'],
    install_requires=[
        'Click',
    ],
    entry_points= {'console_scripts': 
            ['somefunc = yourscript:somefunc']},
 )
```

Answer (score 3):

https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#automatic-script-creation

```
setup(
    …
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'somefunc=yourscript:somefunc',
            'morefunc=yourscript:morefunc',
        ],
    },
…
)
```

Comment: Curiously, the link shows two different modules, while my example tries to pull funcs from the same module...

Comment: Doesn't matter, I'm sure. I believe you can use two entry points from one module.